# What should be modified in a working Python 2 struct example to work in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

While learning about `struct` and by just testing an example provided as one of the answers given for question [Python base64 encoding a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48878855/python-base64-encoding-a-list), I get a Python 3 related error which I don't know how to handle.

Test code:

```
import struct
import base64

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = struct.pack('<{}i'.format(len(l)), *l)
z = base64.b64encode(y)

# ... whatever further processing ...

y = base64.b64decode(z)
l = list(struct.unpack('<{}i'.format(len(y)/4), y))
```

which gives:

```
l = list(struct.unpack('<{}i'.format(len(y)/4), y))
struct.error: bad char in struct format
```

What should be modified to be Python 3 compatible ?

This is merely for exercise & learning; running Python 3.7 on Linux or 3.10 on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the "true division" operator `/` to "floor division" (sometimes called "integer division") `//`:

```py
l = list(struct.unpack('<{}i'.format(len(y)//4), y))
```

This is because in Python 2, division `/` between `int`s give an integer back, with the division rounded down (in the case of a non-zero remainder). In Python 3, division `/` between `int`s results in a `float`, even in the case of the remainder being zero.

The floor division `//` does the same thing as `/` in Python 2. Note however that `//` is also available in Python 2, so the code still works in Python 2 after changing `/` to `//`.

If you're interested in the thought process behind this change, check out [PEP 238](https://peps.python.org/pep-0238/).

Answer (score 1):

`/` always returns a floating-point value in Python 3, where in Python 2 it returned an `int` if both arguments were `int`s. Use `//` instead.

```
l = list(struct.unpack('<{}i'.format(len(y) // 4), y))
```

Since you are using Python 3.7, you can use f-strings instead to simplify this.

```
l = list(struct.unpack(f'<{len(y) // 4}i', y))
```

(To this day, I still wonder why something like `'<*i'` isn't supported to just extract as many values as possible from the byte string argument.)